# Failed Form Submissions Written Anywhere?

Tags: php, html, apache

We've got a customer who has a feedback form whose contents get emails to them.

Email was misconfigured, and looking at Google Analytics, it looks like they missed around 10 form submissions. Would the contents of these forms submissions be logged or written anywhere?

I know the form's actions were not setup to write to a database or anything smart like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately No, They are NOT stored.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no.  They're gone.  Web server logs don't store the actual POST data.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the mail server. Depending on how the email was sent, maybe there is a copy somewhere on a Sent folder (very unlikely though)

Comment: depends on how "Email was misconfigured", if it was a bad email, but a good mail server settings in PHP you've got something in the mail server, for sure, not in sent folder but in the undelivered postmaster mailbox. But if PHP mail settings were so bad that no mail was sent to no server... you're done.